# WITH Common Table Expression vs. CREATE VIEW performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, performance

I have several queries that use a WITH clause, or Common Table Expression, with a UNION ALL statement to recur through a table with a tree like structure in SQL server as described [here](http://www.webinade.com/web-development/creating-recursive-sql-calls-for-tables-with-parent-child-relationships).  Would I see a difference in performance if I were to CREATE that same VIEW instead of including it with the WITH clause and having it generated every time I run the query?  Would it generally be considered good practice to actually CREATE the view since it is used in several queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) and not a [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).  If you're doing [recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), you need to stick with the CTE and not try to roll that into a view.

Views in MS SQL don't give you any performance benefits unless you are [creating clustered indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx) on them.  From the sounds of your question, that is not the case.  You'd likely be better off encapsulating your CTE inside of a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

It looks like a Common Table Expression is the WITH clause that I am currently using.  Is there a performance difference between the CTE and CREAT-ing an actual VIEW?

Comment: no, there should be no performance difference as long as they both use the same query execution plan.

Comment: @Scott: If the same CTE is used in multiple places - function(s), proc(s), etc - would you agree that you create the view rather than have numerous separate instances of the same code?  Assuming it wouldn't be an indexed (AKA materialized) view.

Comment: Sure, I'd go ahead and do that - as long as your CTE code will work in the body of a view (which I assume it should).  Putting it in a view will simplify all of your other queries that use the same code.